# Lyapunov exponent of multiple time series

Tags: real-analysis, dynamical-systems, physics, computational-mathematics

I have multiple time series data that I have generated by varying the initial conditions infinitesimally. I now want to calculate the Lyapunov exponent to identify the sensitivity to initial conditions of the dynamic system that generated the data.

I am really confused on how to approach this as, the guides on [1]http://www.r-bloggers.com/logistic-growth-s-curves-bifurcations-and-lyapunov-exponents-in-r and [2]http://hypertextbook.com/chaos/43.shtml seem like they are using a single time series.. (as far as I understand)

The lya calculation on [2] is like:

```
for (i in 1:length(x)) { 
 lya[i] <- sum(log(abs(x[i]-(2*x[i]*XI[i,]))))/length(x) 
}
```

which is quite confusing as it calculates the mean of just orbit for a single r i.e.: 0.5 then it appears to be calculating the mean of orbit corresponding to the logistic regression with r=0.5 over the first 500 iterations.. I don't see how this implementation actually compares different orbits...

If I have x orbits (from a dynamic system that I do not have an equation for, but just the data) than how should I go about calculating the Lyapunov exponent?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Lyapunov exponent (LE) is a local feature: you cannot characterize a whole dynamical system. Like in the logistic map, you'll have regions with strictly periodic oscillations [characterized by maximal LE (mLE) $\leq 0$], and regions where chaos occurs (with mLE>0).

Sensitivity to initial conditions (ICs) is local in the following sense: choose an IC $x_0$ and a second one, $x_0+\delta x$, that is infinitesimaly displaced from the first. Then you evolve both and measure the mean exponential divergence between them. When you choose another IC, $y_0$, you'll get a different mLE etc.

There are a few methods known to extract mLEs from an experimental time series:

- [Wolf et al., 1985, Determining Lyapunov exponents from a time series](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1985PhyD...16..285W)
- [Rosenstein et al., 1993, A practical method for calculating largest Lyapunov exponents from small data sets](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1993PhyD...65..117R)

They are implemented and available from [here](http://www.mpipks-dresden.mpg.de/~tisean/) and [here](http://www.matjazperc.com/ejp/time.html).